# How can implement my custom ranged for loop?

Tags: c++, c++11, ranged-loops

I do really like Ranged-based-for-loop which is supported by C++11 and above. I'd like for some understanding reason to simulate it. Here is an example:

```
// 1
//#define ranged_for(X, T) \
//  for (std::vector<int>::iterator beg{ T.begin() },\
//      end{ T.end() }; beg != end; X = *beg, ++beg)\

// 2
//#define ranged_for(X, T) \
//  for (std::vector<int>::iterator beg{ T.begin() },\
//      end{ T.end() }; beg != end; ++beg, X = *beg)\

// 3
#define ranged_for(X, T) \
    for (std::vector<int>::iterator beg{ T.begin() },\
        end{ T.end() }; beg != end; ++beg)\
            X = *beg, 



int main(){
    std::vector<int> data{75, 435, 6578, 92, 123};

    auto i{ 0 };
    ranged_for(i, data)
        std::cout << i << std::endl;

    std::cout << std::endl;
    std::cin.get();
    return 0;
}
```

As you can see above the first macro doesn't get the first element `75` but instead the value `0` and the last one is not there. That is because I guess in my main I print `x` before assigning it in the post-iteration part of the loop.

- The second macro crashes the program that is because i think de-referencing the last node (sentry node).
- The third works fine but as you can see after the macro expansion I'll get:

  ```
  i = *beg, std::cout << i << std::endl;
  ```

That is because the line above is treated as a single statement. Is there a better way and explanation. Thank you all good dudes!.

Comment: you can hide the assignment within the conditional statement a la: `beg != end && (X = *beg, true);`

Comment: Why use a macro?  `for(auto const&i : data)` is almost the same length and does what you want.

Comment: Quick curiosity: what is the logic behind `auto i{ 0 };`? I can understand the use of auto to reduce typing out long ugly iterators, but here `int` would be even less characters! Is it just general laziness? Or do you come from a language like javascript where you can just `var` everything?

Comment: Ranged for can be replaced really easy. See https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/range-for

Comment: Third one doesn't work any more if you want/need to have more than one single expression in loop body...

Comment: @JVApen Not *that* easy: A general solution would require to include code to execute in the macro parameters, don't see how you'd otherwise want to get balanced braces.

Comment: @Aconcagua: Yes that is tough. The last assignment of `X = *beg` will not affect the statement of the loop in main that is because the condition will fail when the last value is assigned to `X` thus control jumps after the last statement `std::cout << i;`;

Comment: For some inspiration see how [`BOOST_FOREACH`](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/release/doc/html/foreach.html) macro is [implemented](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/release/boost/foreach.hpp).

Answer (score 1):

Why do you oppose C++ ranged based for loops so much?

```
int i;
ranged_for(i, data)
    // ...
```

vs.

```
for(int i : data)
```

You needed to predeclare `i` so far. You cannot use references this way! Now let's imagine we manage to get it cleverer:

```
ranged_for(int& i, data)
```

vs.

```
for(int& i : data)
```

What did you gain? Using a comma instead of a colon??? Honestly, that's not worth the effort. A scenario more interesing to consider:

```
auto i = data.end();
for(auto j = data.begin(); j != data.end(); ++j)
{
    if(someCondition)
        i = j;
}
if(i != data.end())
{
    // ...
}
```

OK, that's rather rare already. In many, if not most cases you can move the outer if's body into the inner one adding a `break` instruction at the end. And in these few cases you still cannot do so - well, *then* I'd live with the explicit iterator loop – it's not *that* heavy to write...

Comment: I think the OPs point is to write ranged-for like code that works on older (pre C++11) compilers.

Comment: I'm getting `anonymous variadic macros were introduced in C++11` and `extended initializer lists only available with -std=c++11` and some secondary problems with both g++ and clang++ with the pre-C++11 code.

Comment: @TedLyngmo (@#*%!) - you are right... GCC supported variadic macros long before C++11 and as far as I remember, even MSVC did so. One could replace it by a named argument CODE, but that would prevent usage of any commas (for whatever purpose). Heavier problem is that unnamed (well, could add a name) and especially local classes (deadly for this approach) as template arguments aren't supported either. Initialiser lists: well, these were only used in demo to quickly construct a vector...

Answer (score 1):

This should work for both single line and multiline scopes:

```
#define ranged_for(X, T) \
    for(auto it=std::begin(T); it!=std::end(T) && (X=*it,true); ++it)
```

Or a version that can be used to auto deduce the type `X` should be, but it requires an additional macro:

```
#define ranged_for(X, T) \
    {decltype(T)::value_type X; for(auto it=std::begin(T); it!=std::end(T) && (X=*it,true); ++it) {

#define range_end }}

int main(){
    std::vector<int> data{75, 435, 6578, 92, 123};

    ranged_for(i, data)
        std::cout << i << std::endl;
    range_end
}
```

Comment: But requires predeclaring `X` outside the loop - unnecessarily (in majority of cases at least) extending its scope. References cannot be used that way either.

Comment: Sure, but it doesn't seem to be a concern for OP.

Comment: Scope larger than required is bad style. We shouldn't encourage such one...

Comment: Sure. I didn't mean to encourage that. I just tried answering with something that would work better since OP asked for that. I added a version for auto deducing the type too.

Comment: Need to say that addition let's me feel bad. You managed to let C++ look like bash (`if ... fi`). Should I qualify this as even worse style? *Tend* to at least...

Comment: :-) OP's just trying to simulate it with defines. I don't think it's meant to be a replacement for the real thing. It may look ugly but is meant to help OP to do what was in the question.

Comment: Your code doesn't work for custom types, that don't have `begin()` and `end()` member functions, but instead have free function overloads of `begin()` and `end()`. [See example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/5ee188b374f9c103).

Comment: That is true. The second one won't work on anything but containers with `value_type` either. It's not a fully fledged replacement for a range based for loop for sure, but it handles more cases than the original code.

Comment: Here is a little proof-of-concept how the 1st one could be made more flexible: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/9af163a803fdffde

Comment: Nice. I think you should make that into an answer of its own. I'll vote for it! :)